# How do I make MIDI files sound the same in Linux as in Windows?

Tags: linux, midi

I have created a MIDI file using Anvil Studio in Windows. When playing the file with the MIDI editor Rosegarden in Linux (openSUSE Tumbleweed), the MIDI file sounds different.

Now, I know that MIDI files don't contain any music themselves and that it depends on the device which sound is played.
From what I have read so far it looks like Anvil Studio is using the Microsoft GS Wavetable Software Synthesizer and that this is what makes the MIDI file sound the way it does.

Is there a way to make the MIDI file sound the same in Linux? E.g. by specifying a soundfont or using a certain Software Synthesizer?

Comment: AFAIK you will need the same sound fonts on both OS. Also player should have quite close characteristics in sense of interpret MIDI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Get the `gm.dls` file out of `\windows\system32\drivers\`;
2. convert it into a .sf2 sound font with a tool like Viena or Awave;
3. configure the Linux synthesizer (probably TiMidity++ or FluidSynth) to use that file.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Exactly what I needed. There seem to be some minor differences concerning relative volume of the different channels, but other than that the sounds are the same.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same issue, just dowloaded original Windows midifonts from here and attached to my software:
https://musical-artifacts.com/artifacts/713